# How do I display the count of checked boxes in react? The function itself works but cannot to display count in the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

The count outside the handleCheckCount function is 0, so how can pass down the actual count of the checked boxed in the  tag in render? I tried passing down the state as 
Total Number of Checkbox Selected:{this.state.count} but that just returns 0. 
If I console.log(count) inside the handleCheckCount function it display the number of the checked boxes in the console but outside it returns 0.

```
  state={
    checked: false,
    count: 0
  }
  handleCheckCount=()=> {
    let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    let count= this.state.count
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].type === "checkbox" && input[i].checked === true) {
        count++

      }
    }
    console.log(count)
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th className="select_all">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="parent"
              onClick={this.onSelectAll.bind(this)} onChange={this.handleCheckCount}/>
          </th>
          <th>Score</th>
          <th>FirstName</th>
          <th>LastName</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>

        <h2>Total Number of Checkbox Selected: </h2>

      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
class App extends React.Component {

   state={
    checked: false,
    count: 0
  }

  handleCheckCount=(e)=> {
    // let input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    const { checked, type } = e.target;
    // let count= this.state.count
    // for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (type === "checkbox" && checked === true) {
        this.setState(state => state.count++, this.logCount)
      } else {
        this.setState(state => state.count--, this.logCount)
      }
    // }
  }

  logCount() {
    console.log(this.state.count);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th className="select_all">
            <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="parent" onChange={e => this.handleCheckCount(e)}/>
          </th>
          <th>Score</th>
          <th>FirstName</th>
          <th>LastName</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>

        <h2>Total Number of Checkbox Selected: {this.state.count}</h2>

      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Your problem was that you didn't update your state, just the scoped variable `count` inside the function (the same one you also logged).
I also added an `else` block to decrease the count, and removed the `onClick` listener.

**Update:** There's no need to use `getElementsbyTagName` and the for loop. You can use the event to get the target and its properties.

[See on Codepen](https://codepen.io/OPerel/pen/abvBrBr?editors=1012)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful, but for some reason, the number is being incremented by 2, not 1. So, 1 checkbox count showing as 2, 2nd checkbox count showing as 4. I want it to increment by 1.

Comment: I added a second input in the codepen above and it's working fine. Have a look

Comment: That works great. In the codepen when I check the boxes it counts as 1 then 2 but on my end, the count starts from 2 then 4; decrements by 2 as well.

Comment: I can't tell without seeing the code but maybe you're calling `handleCheckCount` twice some how?